# Using Point lights in Unity3D Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, lighting

I am trying to use a point light animation for my game. It runs fine in Editor with Diffuse, Bumped Specular and VertexLit shaders. However it doesn't work on any Mobile shaders provided by default.

Is there a way to use Point lights in Android? Or is there any shader which can work on mobiles and supports point lights too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer - [this post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/280030/ios-custom-specular-shader.html) on UnityAnswer helped me. I am reposting the Custom Shader here -

```
// Specular, Normal Maps with Main Texture
// Fragment based
Shader "SpecTest/SpecTest5" 
{
    Properties 
    {
        _Shininess ("Shininess", Range (0, 1.5)) = 0.078125
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _SpecColor ("Specular Color", Color) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _BumpMap ("Bump Map", 2D) = "bump" {}
        _NormalStrength ("Normal Strength", Range (0, 1.5)) = 1
    } // eo Properties
    SubShader 
    {
        // pass for 4 vertex lights, ambient light & first pixel light
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf MobileBlinnPhong

        fixed4 LightingMobileBlinnPhong (SurfaceOutput s, fixed3 lightDir, fixed3 halfDir, fixed atten)
        {
            fixed diff = saturate(dot (s.Normal, lightDir));
            fixed nh = saturate(dot (s.Normal, halfDir)); //Instead of injecting the normalized light+view, we just inject view, which is provided as halfasview in the initial surface shader CG parameters

            fixed spec = pow (nh, s.Specular*128) * s.Gloss;

            fixed4 c;
            c.rgb = (s.Albedo * _LightColor0.rgb * diff + _SpecColor.rgb * spec) * (atten*2);
            c.a = 0.0;
            return c;
        }

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
            float2 uv_BumpMap;
        };

        // User-specified properties
        uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
        uniform sampler2D _BumpMap;
        uniform float _Shininess;
        uniform float _NormalStrength;
        uniform fixed4 _Color;      

        float3 expand(float3 v) { return (v - 0.5) * 2; } // eo expand 

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
            half4 tex = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
               o.Albedo = tex.rgb;
               o.Gloss = tex.a;
               o.Alpha = tex.a;
               o.Specular = _Shininess;

            // fetch and expand range-compressed normal
            float3 normalTex = UnpackNormal (tex2D (_BumpMap, IN.uv_BumpMap));
            float3 normal = normalTex * _NormalStrength;
            o.Normal = normal;
        } // eo surf

        ENDCG
    } 
        //Fallback "Specular"
  } // eo Shader
```

Remember to increase strength though. And obviously it's too costly on frame rate. I need it for just an animation, so I used it.

Comment: @pglynn I can't for another 8 hours :-(